# ParcelJS with --target node --bundle-node-modules cannot resolve dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, worker, parceljs

I have a project with 2 source files + node_modules that works fine to build with parcel and run in development but as soon as I change:

```
parcel build src/index.ts src/stressedWorker.ts --no-minify --target node
```

into:

```
parcel build src/index.ts src/stressedWorker.ts --no-minify --target node --bundle-node-modules
```

it throws the following:

```
    C:\Kod\ParcelTest\src\index.ts:17:33: Cannot resolve dependency 'worker_threads'
    at Resolver.resolve (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Resolver.js:71:17)
    at async Bundler.resolveAsset (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Bundler.js:433:18)
    at async Bundler.resolveDep (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Bundler.js:484:14)
    at async C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Bundler.js:608:26
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async Bundler.loadAsset (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Bundler.js:599:21)
    at async Bundler.processAsset (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\Bundler.js:557:5)
    at async PromiseQueue._runJob (C:\Kod\ParcelTest\node_modules\parcel\src\utils\PromiseQueue.js:48:7)
```

Worth noting is that the project uses the experimental Workers feature.

What am I missing and what can do?

Comment: probably worker_threads are not in the list of the modules which parcel excludes as native modules(such as fs or http)